# List data type that starts with digit

Tags: haskell

```
data Identifier = Identifier [Num:(Char|Num)]
```

I'm trying to do something like the code above in Haskell. I want to make a data type for a list that has to start with a digit, but can contain either lowercase characters or digits in it's tail.

Comment: In that case, you can write this as `data Identifier = Identifier Num [Either 
 Char Num]`. So here the start item is a separate field. An identifier however usually starts with a `Char`, not with a `Num`.

Comment: We're making a weird embedded language for college. Would this also work if the number is part of the list?

Comment: no, since the elements of a list all have the same type. Haskell does not treat a list special: if you write `[a]`, you write `[] a`, with `[]` a type constructor. So in fact the compiler does not (have) to understand the concepts of lists at all. By using a field however, you make your data type "stronger", since (a) it is impossible to define an empty identifier, and (b) you enforce that the first item is a list. You can then make some functions that do the parsing and rendering of the `Identifier`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell a list is not a "special" type. In fact one could define it like:

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
```

So that means that the compiler does not *have* to understand what a list is, and how a list works. For Haskell `[a]` is just another representation of `[] a`, and it simply sees the type constructor for a list. This thus means that for the compiler `[a : b]` as type is non-sensical, since `(:)` is *not* a type constructor, it is a *data constructor*.

You could model this with the first character as a separate parameter, like:

```
data Identifier = Identifier Int [Either Int Char]
```

You can then for example textually represent your `Identifier`, with:

```
import Data.Char(intToDigit)

class Render a where
    render :: a -> String

instance Render Identifier where
    print (Identifier n ns) = intToDigit n : map iprint ns
        where iprint (Left a) = intToDigit a
              iprint (Right b) = b
```

Here our `Identifier` data type thus excludes two cases:

1. an "empty" identifier (with no characters at all); and
2. an identifier that starts with a `Char`.

You might want to define a `Digit` type and `Lower` type as well, that act like subsets of `Int` and `Char` respectively to further restrict the possible values in your type, since right now the `Int` can have values outside the `[0..9]` range, and `Char` can have any character.

You can also write functions to parse a string into an `Identifier`. In fact, by properly "engineering" the data types, you can exclude a lot of values that should be impossible, and thus the compiler can help you ensure that your functions do *not* return values that should be considered invalid.

The above technique is used in some libraries in Haskell as well. The [**`Data.List.NonEmpty`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) module for example defines a [data constructor `(:|)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#NonEmpty):

> ```
> data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]
> ```

So here one defines a `NonEmpty` list again with a constructor that enforces that the a `NonEmpty` has an element, and a (possibly empty) list of remaining elements.

Comment: List *syntax*, though, is special. The language allows the otherwise invalid "name" `[]` to be used as the type constructor and the data constructor for the empty list, and additionally allows `[x,y,z]` as syntactic sugar for `x : y : z : []`.

Comment: @chepner: yes, but what I mean here is that a Haskell compiler should not need to treat the list *type* differenty. But you are indeed correct that there is some syntactical sugar and ond syntax for lists.